Angular package.json - updated npm packages to a newer version including dependencies
I have an ionic Angular project with this dependencies in package.json:
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
"@capacitor/android": "5.3.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "^5.7.8",
"@capacitor/network": "^5.0.8",
"@capacitor/push-notifications": "^5.1.2",
"@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^4.0.0",
"@ionic/storage-angular": "^4.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
"ionic-color-picker": "^1.0.3",
"ionicons": "^7.0.0",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"net": "^1.0.2",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
"stompjs": "^2.3.3",
"swiper": "^11.0.4",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.13.0"

Now I will update this two dependencies because a new module I will introduce required version 6.2.0:
@capacitor/android": "5.3.0",
"@capacitor/ios": "^5.7.8",

I am a dummy concerning npm modules and dependent version. Is there a command I can execute in order to upgrade to version 6.2.0 or do I have to do it manuelly.
My aim would be that I am not landing in a dependency hell.
